# I can't get an alphabetical sorting formula to work?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to use [the following method](https://chandoo.org/wp/sorting-text-in-excel-using-formulas/) to sort the words in the cells alphabetically.

However, when I apply it to my data, it doesn't work.

[image: v]

In cell A7 I write:

```
=COUNTIF($F$7:$L$7,"<="&F7)
```

Cell F7 contains the word "Action" which should be the first word alphabetically. However it writes 5 as if it's the last word alphabetically.

Comment: It looks like your other words in the row (`Comedy`, `Drama`, etc) all have a space at the beginning.  So instead of "Comedy" it's actually " Comedy".  The space would be causing the problem.  Make sure extra spaces are removed from your data to avoid this issue.

Comment: @tigeravatar You're absolutely right. Thank you so much!